# Error check in y or no answer (C)

Tags: c

The problem with current code I have is that if first time question in answered wrong aka answer is not y or n, program won't record the answer second time after it asks to try again.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>

void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
clock_t goal=mseconds+clock();
while(goal>clock());
}

void check_anwser(char a){
    do{
        if((a=='y')||(a=='n')){
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("\nIncorrect answer, please try again\n");
            printf(":");
            scanf("%s",&a);
            continue;
        }
    }while((a!='y')&&(a!='n'));
}

int main(){

    char start;
    int load;

    printf("************************************\n");
    printf("*Welcome to 'noname' 0.01          *\n");
    printf("*Do you want to start the game y/n?*\n");
    printf("************************************\n");

    printf(":");
    scanf("%s",&start);
    if((start!='y')&&(start!='n')){
        check_anwser(start);
    }

    if(start=='y'){
        for(load=0;load<100;load+=5){
            printf("Loading %d",load);
            delay(100);
            system("cls");
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Shutting down");
        for(load=0;load<3;load++){
            printf(".");
            delay(600);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions are actually welcome at this point, I'm really new to C and coding in general... Guessing questions will be asked often.

Comment: Note that `clock` is really a bad time-keeper. First of all there's no guarantee that the unit is in milliseconds. Secondly, it's specified in multiple places to count only the current process CPU time, not wall clock. Thirdly, a busy-wait like yours will bog down the processor spending useless CPU cycles.

Comment: since `start` is a `char` variable, you should use `%c` instead of `%s`. This `scanf("%s",&start);` --> `scanf(" %c",&start);`

Comment: @achal thank you. This didn't fix the issue though, after saying **Incorrect answer, please try again...**, program won't accept **y** as an answer and will go straight to **Shutting down** part

Comment: @user3121023 the reply for **achal** applies to you too I guess

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude do you have a better suggestion? I would like to get any help I can

Comment: @user3121023 so do I need change the `check_answer` to be `char`?

Comment: @user3121023 thank you mate

Comment: @user3121023 I tried using `usleep()` didn't work, I also tried using just the `sleep` that didn't work too :\

Comment: Mind `scanf()` is reading a string, not a character. The difference is important because you are overwriting memory out of bounds of your variable. `a` can only accommodate 1 char, not a string, not even a single char plus the null terminator that forms a valid string. This code is invoking undefined behavior and will most likely crash in some situations. Use `getchar()` to fetch a single character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because as you are using the function to check for the right answer, the new character that the user input is not being passed to **start** variable. **start** variable has old value saved into it, therefore even if the user enters the correct value it's not being saved anywhere and IF statement is checking from the **start variable** that has old value.

I've fixed it here for you and following is what I've changed in your code.

**Before**

```
check_anwser(start);
```

**Now**

```
start = check_anwser(start);
```

**Full code with changes**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>

void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
clock_t goal=mseconds+clock();
while(goal>clock());
}

char check_anwser(char a){
    do{
        if((a=='y')||(a=='n')){
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("\nIncorrect answer, please try again\n");
            printf(":");
            scanf("%s",&a);

        }
    }while((a!='y')||(a!='n'));
    return a;
}


int main(){

    char start;
    int load;

    printf("************************************\n");
    printf("*Welcome to 'noname' 0.01          *\n");
    printf("*Do you want to start the game y/n?*\n");
    printf("************************************\n");

    printf(":");
    scanf("%s",&start);
    if((start!='y')&&(start!='n')){
        start = check_anwser(start);
    }

    if(start=='y'){
        for(load=0;load<100;load+=5){
            printf("Loading %d",load);
            delay(100);
            system("cls");
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Shutting down");
        for(load=0;load<3;load++){
            printf(".");
            delay(600);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Also I've made the changes in your **check_anwser** function to return **char**

Comment: Yep thank you, as I said again I'm no to C and coding in general

Comment: May I ask for what reason is the `return a;` needed?

Comment: To return the new character user has entered.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `fgets` to read the choice. One advantage of this is that `fgets` will include the newline if the array is large enough. Here an array of `[3]` only allows space for a character, a newline and a `'\0'`. If the array does not contain a newline, there are more characters waiting in `stdin`. This helps to clean `stdin` of excess characters.
For the delay, this is using `nanosleep`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int fgetsanswer ( char *choice, FILE *fin);
void delay ( unsigned int seconds, unsigned int nseconds);

int main ( void) {

    char start;
    int load;

    printf ( "************************************\n");
    printf ( "*Welcome to 'noname' 0.01          *\n");
    printf ( "*Do you want to start the game y/n?*\n");
    printf ( "************************************\n");

    printf ( ":");
    if ( fgetsanswer ( &start, stdin)) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ( start == 'y') {
        printf ( "\rLoading  ");
        fflush ( stdout);//no trailing newline so make sure printf prints
        for ( load = 0; load <= 100; load += 5) {
            delay ( 0, 600000000);//for a 0.6 second delay
            printf ( "\rLoading %d", load);
            fflush ( stdout);//no trailing newline so make sure printf prints
        }
    }
    else {
        printf ( "Shutting down");
        fflush ( stdout);//no trailing newline so make sure printf prints
        for ( load = 0; load < 3; load++) {
            printf ( " .");
            fflush ( stdout);//no trailing newline so make sure printf prints
            delay ( 0, 700000000);//for a 0.7 second delay
        }
    }
    printf ( "\n");
    return 0;
}

void delay ( unsigned int seconds, unsigned int nseconds)
{
    struct timespec ts = {0};

    ts.tv_sec = seconds;
    ts.tv_nsec = nseconds;
    while ( nanosleep ( &ts, &ts)) {}
}

int fgetsanswer ( char *choice, FILE *fin) {
    char input[3] = "";//can hold one char a newline and a '\0'

    do {
        if ( fgets ( input, sizeof input, fin)) {
            if ( !strchr ( input, '\n')) {//is there a newline?
                while ( !strchr ( input, '\n')) {//call until newline is found to clear input
                    if ( !fgets ( input, sizeof input, fin)) {
                        fprintf ( stderr, "\nEOF problem\n");
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
                input[0] = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "\nEOF problem\n");
            *choice = 0;
            return 1;
        }
        if ( input[0] != 'y' && input[0] != 'n') {
            printf ( "\nenter y or n\n:");
            fflush ( stdout);//no trailing newline so make sure printf prints
        }
    } while ( input[0] != 'y' && input[0] != 'n');

    *choice = input[0];//assign the answer to the pointer

    return 0;
}
```